# How to skip checkout step in opencart?

Tags: php, opencart, payment-gateway

I want to skip step 5 from my checkout process.I want to open step 6 instead of step 5 from step 2 in opencart checkout process.

Visit http://www.mycreativestore.com

Comment: why do you want to skip the payment method step?

Comment: Because I am using only one payment method i.e.payumoney payment gateway.

Comment: Is your payment method listed in the step during checkout?

Answer (score -2):

To skip the checkout step, you can do the following :

- Fill in the details during checkout
- Go till the payment options page, but don't do the payment
- Go back or click on cancel or refresh the page.
- Your order will go in Pending status.

Now, if you have the backend access *you can change the **order status** to **confirm***. You have now skipped the checkout step and placed the order without payment.

I tried this you can check the Order Id 2 :

See below snapshot :

[image]

Comment: When you follow this procedure the order status is "missing orders"

Comment: @MehravishTemkar I have attached the snapshot for your reference.

Comment: Okay consider you are the owner of the site. Someone has tried checkout out but for some reason changes the decision of buying during the last step. Assume around 10 users have done it in a day. So now you have 10 missing order (pending orders if you want to call them). How can you decide which orders to confirm in such case (unless you can read the minds of the end users of course)?